# Why can't I access $(this) in ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The issue is pretty straight forward, I can not reference `$(this)` in the success section of my jQuery ajax call, for example this does not work (to hide the clicked element):

```
    $('.assigned').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.post("@Url.Action("method", "controller")",
        {
            TicketId: $(this).data("ticketid"),

        },
        function (data, status) {

            $(this).hide();
        });

    });
```

its worth noting the data is sent. However this hides the element just fine:

```
    $('.assigned').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).hide();
        $.post("@Url.Action("method", "controller")",
        {
            TicketId: $(this).data("ticketid"),

        },
        function (data, status) {



        });

    });
```

Why is this happening?

Tested in FireFox

Comment: `"@Url.Action("method", "controller")"` Double quotes in double quotes. Don't you have syntax colors? The console must be yelling

Comment: @JeremyThille : this is ASP.NET Razor syntax. `@Url.Action()` method is executed on server-side and generates a fully qualified URL. ([more information about Razor](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-%28c%29))

Comment: Yeah sorry, I just didnt filter out my razor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to ask yourself, where are you in this code? What would *this* apply to?

You are currently in:

```
function(data, status){

}
```

or:

```
$.post("@Url.Action("method", "controller")",
            {
                TicketId: $(this).data("ticketid"),

            }
```

Thus *this* would apply to your function and not to your element.

Just do:

```
$('.assigned').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
         $this.hide();
        $.post("@Url.Action("method", "controller")",
        {
            TicketId: $this.data("ticketid"),

        },
        function (data, status) {

            $this //will work here

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign `this` to a variable on click and then hide it using the variable:

```
$('.assigned').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $t = $(this);
    $.post("@Url.Action("method", "controller")",
    {
        TicketId: $(this).data("ticketid"),

    },
    function (data, status) {
        $t.hide();
    });

});
```